# Why did my reputation go from 941 to 937?

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation suddenly went from 941 to 937, and the following things happened right before the rep change

1. I did not receive any downvotes
2. I received an upvote which leads to +10

The upvote should have got me 951 rep, any reason for getting 937?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can audit your reputation via [your profile](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation). One of your questions was deleted (through an [automatic process](/help/roomba)) resulting in the loss 14 reputation (the question had two upvotes and three downvotes).

[image]

Comment: Btw the -14 rep did not show up anywhere on my side

Comment: That is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219652/295232).

Comment: Ah ok thx for the info. Does it show up on the reputation tab in the profile?

Comment: Yes, that's where the screenshot is from.

Comment: This is a test comment.